# Append/prepend data to CSV column

Tags: powershell, append, prepend

I have spent over a week researching this question and none of the helps have worked.  I started with this:

```
$File = "C:\FOLDER\index - Copy.csv"
Import-Csv -Delim ',' $File |
    ForEach-Object {$_.col1 = "C:\FOLDER\$($_.col1)"; $_} |
    Export-Csv Index2.csv -Delim ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

which I found elsewhere on this site and modified as I would expect.  But I received this error:

```
Exception setting "col1": "The property 'col1' cannot be found on this object.
Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:2 char:69
+ Import-Csv -Delim ',' $File | ForEach-Object {$_.col1 = "C:\FOLDER\$($_.col1)";$_ ...
+                                                                      ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

All I want to do is take a CSV file that looks like this:

```
Path,Filename
123456789,654321
234567891,543216
345678912,432165
```

and ultimately end with this:

```
Path,Filename
C:\FOLDER\123456789.jpg,654321.jpg
C:\FOLDER\234567891.jpg,543216.jpg
C:\FOLDER\345678912.jpg,432165.jpg
```

Comment: What is not clear about the error? Your CSV does not have a column named "col1". Use the actual column name(s) instead.

Comment: D'OH!  I've been looking at this for so long that I just needed a different pair of eyes.  Thank you.